# Editing Embedded PowerPoint from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I have an embedded PowerPoint presentation in an Excel workbook. How can I edit this (open, copy slides, add data to slides, close) using VBA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. Add a reference to the PowerPoint Object Model to your VBA application**

From the VBA window, choose **Tools | References**
Look for **Microsoft Powerpoint 12.0 Object Library** and check it

**2. Select and activate the PowerPoint presentation object**

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Object 1").Select
Selection.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
```

Note: this code assumes that the PowerPoint object is named **Object 1** (look in the top left corner to see what it's really named) and that it is on the active sheet.

**3. Get a reference to the Presentation object**

```
Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set p = Selection.Object
```

**4. Manipulate it**

All the methods and properties of a presentation object are available to you. Here's an example of adding a slide:

```
p.Slides.Add 1, ppLayoutBlank
```

**5. Deselect it**

The easiest way is just to select a cell.

```
[a1].Select
```

Hope that helps!