# How can I edit a PowerPoint presentation embedded in Excel using Excel VBA and userform

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am building a database with information on a large collection of product designs. I chose to use an Excel file with userform input for the design details so as to easily filter by detail, then select a link to the corresponding page that contains an embedded PowerPoint with photos and design notes. At the moment I have a template that copies into a new tab, renames and creates a link to the tab in a directory based on text box input of part number. I might be asking too much but I'd also like the userform to add text to preexisting text boxes within the PowerPoint presentation. Everything up to this point works rather well.

I found a similar question and tried my hand at coding several times.

[Editing Embedded PowerPoint from Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124375/editing-embedded-powerpoint-from-excel-vba)

It was helpful in understanding but it didn't work for me in this context:

```
Private Sub cmdAddSlide_Click()

    template = "Slide Template"

    'Hide the sheet
    ufrmAddSlide.Hide

    'Copy the template to create a new sheet.
    Sheets(template).Select
    Sheets(template).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    'Make the sheet visible in case the template is hidden.
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    'Rename the sheet.
    ActiveSheet.Name = txtPartNumber

    'Add data to powerpoint object.
    Worksheets(Me.txtPartNumber.Value).Shapes("Object 1").Select 
    Selection.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
    Dim p As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set p = Selection.Object
    ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("operationaltext1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Me.txtPartNumber.Value
    [a1].Select

    'Bring main sheet back to front if necessary.
    If chkBringToFront = False Then
        Sheets("Directory").Select
    End If

    'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Directory")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    With ws    
        'Create a link to the part design page with the part number text.
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(lRow, 1), Address:="", 
        SubAddress:=Me.txtPartNumber.Value & "!A1", 
        TextToDisplay:=Me.txtPartNumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtPartNumber.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtCustomer.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.cboSkydrol.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cboPneumatic.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.cboFuel.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.cboRedOil.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.cboSpace.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.cboStyle.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.txtWeight.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.txtMaxPressure.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 11).Value = Me.txtOperatingPressure.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 12).Value = Me.txtProofPressure.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 13).Value = Me.txtBurstPressure.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 14).Value = Me.txtAmbientTemperature.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 15).Value = Me.txtFluidTemperature.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 16).Value = Me.txtPullIn.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 17).Value = Me.txtDropOut.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 18).Value = Me.txtCoilResistance.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 19).Value = Me.txtLeakage.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 20).Value = Me.txtFlow.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 21).Value = Me.txtNotes.Value
    End With

    'Clear all inputs.
    Me.cboSkydrol.Value = ""
    Me.cboPneumatic.Value = ""
    Me.cboFuel.Value = ""
    Me.cboRedOil.Value = ""
    Me.cboSpace.Value = ""
    Me.cboStyle.Value = ""
    Me.txtAmbientTemperature.Value = ""
    Me.txtBurstPressure.Value = ""
    Me.txtCoilResistance.Value = ""
    Me.txtDropOut.Value = ""
    Me.txtFlow.Value = ""
    Me.txtFluidTemperature.Value = ""
    Me.txtLeakage.Value = ""
    Me.txtMaxPressure.Value = ""
    Me.txtNotes.Value = ""
    Me.txtOperatingPressure.Value = ""
    Me.txtPartNumber.Value = ""
    Me.txtProofPressure.Value = ""
    Me.txtPullIn.Value = ""
    Me.txtWeight.Value = ""
    Me.txtCustomer.Value = ""
End Sub
```

The PowerPoint Presentation opened in a separate window but nothing was changed. Also, the rest of my VBA code didn't execute. Though I'm only a week into my understanding of ExcelVBA coding. So far has been just trying Frankenstein code from several sites.

Can I do this without opening the slide in a separate window?

I'd appreciate some input. :)

The workbook contains worksheets "Slide Template" and "Directory".

The PowerPoint slide is named "Object 1".

The destination texbox within the slide is named "operationaltext1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some code that inserts a powerpoint slide, adds text to it and also reads the text back

if you only need one slide, then this is for you

```
Option Explicit

Sub testPPslide()

    ' NOTE: this adds a slide everytime the code is run
    ' it will be the standard "click here to add title" slide

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c1:d1") = ""

    Dim pps As OLEObject

    Set pps = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add( _
            ClassType:="PowerPoint.Slide.12", _
            Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False)

'   pps.Verb Verb:=xlOpen                     ' this edits slide in standalone PP app
'   pps.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary                  ' this one opens PP in excel
    pps.Top = 40
    pps.Left = 60

    Dim ps As powerpoint.Slide
    Set ps = pps.Object

    ps.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "cccccccccc"
    ps.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "this works"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c1") = ps.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d1") = ps.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfect! I am running in to another issue now though where the object isn't found unless the slide is preexisting. If I create the slide first it works great but if I try to do it from VBA from the same click event I get the error "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Object property of the OLEObject class." I believe the code is running all at once and not finding the new slide yet. Is there a way to have the slide copied first, then input the values from a single button click?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I explained myself well enough. I can write code to insert a slide. That isn't the issue. I have code that copies an existing worksheet with a PowerPoint slide already embedded. I just need to add text to existing text boxes within the slide. I did it this way because the template I am copying has formatting already. i.e: font, size, header and footer, date box, 4 separate informational boxes and their placement location on the slide. I'm thinking that the error results from trying to copy the slide, rename it AND input text from a single "cmdOK" button click.

Comment: just to confirm, it is a slide, not a presentation. is that correct? ....  why are you copying the slide? that part is not clear to me because you said that the worksheet has an embedded powerpoint (slide/presentation)

Comment: Yes, it is in fact a slide, and not a presentation. Within the excel workbook there are two worksheets. One is named "Directory" and the other is "Slide Template". "Slide Template" has a PPslide embedded. This slide is formatted to my liking. When the command button "Add Slide" is clicked on the userform I created, the text boxes input into the "Directory" so it's content is searchable. This command button also creates a copy of the sheet "Slide Template" and renames it. I'd also like the same command button to take text box input from the userform and edit the new sheet that was just created.

Answer (score 0):

this one works on presentations

example code

```
Option Explicit


Sub testPPpresentation()

    ' NOTE: adds a PP presentation to the worksheet each time it is run

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c1:d1") = ""

    Dim aaa As OLEObject
    Set aaa = Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add( _
                ClassType:="PowerPoint.Show.12", _
                Link:=False, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=False)

'   aaa.Verb Verb:=xlOpen       ' this edits the presentation in standalone PP app
'   aaa.Verb Verb:=xlPrimary    ' this one edits the presentation in excel

    aaa.Top = 90
    aaa.Left = 60

    Dim ppp As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Set ppp = aaa.Object

    ppp.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "cccccccccc"
    ppp.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "this works"

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c1") = ppp.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d1") = ppp.Slides(1).Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text

End Sub
```